# directorylist in shell sh-Script

Tags: linux, bash, shell

i have a sh-Script with:

```
  #!/bin/sh

  dirs=( $(find . -maxdepth 1 -type d -printf '%P\n') )
        echo "There are ${#dirs[@]} dirs in the current path"

        let i=1

        for dir in "${dirs[@]}"; do
            echo "$((i++)) $dir"
        done
        answer=2

        echo "you selected ${dirs[$answer]}!"
```

But i got the error:

> symfonymenu.sh: Syntax error: "(" unexpected (expecting "}")

its the line ...dirs=

I like to echo all available directories in a folder that user can select it in a prompt interface.

Answer (score 3):

You use features from the bash shell, so you should execute the script in bash. Change the first line to:

```
#!/bin/bash
```

`/bin/sh` can be any POSIX-compatible shell, for example on Ubuntu it's dash.

Comment: `/bin/sh` is the POSIX shell, which is based on, but not equivalent to, the original Bourne shell.

Answer (score 2):

That's a bash script so you should make sure that you're running it with `bash`. Call it as `bash script.sh`. Also you should start your index from 0 not 1: `let i=0`.